# Woocommerce adding Custom Attributes (taxonomy) to mail template as array

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Im hooking into the woocommerce email-notification for admins, when an order is placed. Im doing this from a plugin. Im trying to add a custom table which will help in day-to-day work.
Code is working except trying to assign a custom attribute to an array (commented out sections).

```
//  $prodct_liter[] = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_liter' );
```

This causes an "internal error" and the email is not sent. My suspicion is that the custom taxonomies dont neccessarily want to go into an array? How can I add them to an array like I can with "name" and "qty"?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_frakt_storrelser', 10, 2 );

function add_frakt_storrelser( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {
if ( $sent_to_admin ) {

  echo '<p></p><table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1"><thead><tr>';
    $product_list = '';
    $order_item = $order->get_items();

    foreach( $order_item as $product ) {

        $prodct_name[] = $product['name']; 
        $prodct_quantity[] = $product['qty'];
    //  $prodct_liter[] = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_liter' );
    }
    echo '<th class="td" scope="col">';
    $product_list = implode( '</th>
        <th class="td" scope="col">', $prodct_name );
    echo "$product_list";

    echo '</th></tr><tr><th class="td" scope="col">';
    $product_list = implode( '</th>
        <th class="td" scope="col">', $prodct_quantity );
    echo "$product_list";

    //echo '</th></tr><tr><th class="td" scope="col">';
    //$product_list = implode( '</th>
    //  <th class="td" scope="col">', $prodct_liter );
    //echo "$product_list";

    echo '</th></tr></thead>';  
echo '</tbody></table>';



 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I figured it out, I still have a lot to learn about handling arrays I think.

```
$order_item = $order->get_items();
```

Does not return an array which contains the attributes Im after. So I need to pass the product id to a command which will get me the full product array.

```
$prodct_id = $product['product_id'];
    $ting = wc_get_product( $prodct_id);
```

and then I can get the attributes.

```
 $prodct_liter[] = $ting->get_attribute( 'pa_liter' );
```

Full code (Still figuring out some bugs)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_frakt_storrelser', 10, 2 );

function add_frakt_storrelser( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {
if ( $sent_to_admin ) {

  echo '<p></p><table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1"><thead><tr>';
    $product_list = '';
    $order_item = $order->get_items();

    foreach( $order_item as $product ) {
        $prodct_id = $product['product_id'];
        $ting = wc_get_product( $prodct_id);
        $prodct_name[] = $product['name']; 
        $prodct_quantity[] = $product['qty'];
        if (!empty($ting->get_attribute( 'pa_kolli-stor' ))) {
            $prodct_kolli[] = $ting->get_attribute( 'pa_kolli-stor' );
        }
        else {
            $prodct_kolli[] = 1;
        }
        $prodct_liter[] = $ting->get_attribute( 'pa_liter' );
    }
    echo '<th class="td" scope="col">';
    $product_list = implode( '</th>
        <th class="td" scope="col">', $prodct_name );
    echo "$product_list";

    echo '</th></tr><tr><th class="td" scope="col">';
    $product_list = implode( '</th>
        <th class="td" scope="col">', $prodct_quantity );
    echo "$product_list";

    echo '</th></tr><tr><th class="td" scope="col">';
    $product_list = implode( '</th>
        <th class="td" scope="col">', $prodct_kolli );
    echo "$product_list";

    echo '</th></tr><tr><th class="td" scope="col">';
    $product_list = implode( '</th>
        <th class="td" scope="col">', $prodct_liter );
    echo "$product_list";

    echo '</th></tr></thead></table>';
  }
}
```